# wrong proportions with the grid system

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build a responsive website and I'm stuck with this problem: 
I'm applying the grid system to a `div` but I'm getting wrong proportions as shows the image below:

**In 320px viewport width:**

[image]

**In the device toolbar with a 320px  too:**

[image]

I wanna know the reasons behind that behaviour. 
I think It's something to the viewport width ??
and thank you in advance

here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blue-box">
 <p class="container-3"><span  data-aos="fade-right"  data-aos-duration="1800"
    class="word-bb-1">well </span><span
   class="word-bb-2"
    data-aos="fade-left"  data-aos-duration="2000">I think your first
  question</span>
  <span class="word-bb-3" data-aos="fade-right"   data-aos-duration="1500">is about Amine right</span>
  <span class="word-bb-mark" data-aos="fade-down-left"  data-aos-duration="2000">?!!!</span>
  <img src="../vector/murva 1.1.png" class="img-box" alt=""  data-aos="fade-down"
   data-aos-duration="1500">
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .blue-box {
    margin-top: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 33vh;
    background-color: #33cccc;
  }

  .img-box {
    width: 40vw;
        position: relative;
        left: -7vw;  }

  .container-3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50vw 50vw;
    grid-template-rows: 16vh auto 3vh auto;
    color: #ffffcc;
    font-family: Roboto;
    grid-column-gap: 5vw;
  }

 .word-bb-1 {
   font-size: 10vh;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   margin-top: 5vh;
   margin-left: 10vw;
  }

  .word-bb-2 {
    margin-top: 8vh;
  }

  .word-bb-3 {
    font-size: 7vw;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .word-bb-mark {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1/3
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you are going to have a lot of unexpected results using grid to string together words. You could accomplish this same thing very easily using em/rem units or vw/vh units, combined with dynamic padding/margins. If possible, I would recommend you check this out on a widescreen monitor, because I don't believe it is appearing the way you want it to.

Comment: your code is not working as what you have shown on the image.please use bootstrap grid system to over code this issue

Comment: You are making the text dependant on the viewport HEIGHT, are both pictures taken with the same viewport height? If you wan't both to behave the same related to the width then use `vw` units and not `vh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: right` to your `.word-bb-1` span. It is the remaining space between the word "Well" and the end o the stretched span.

Any element inside a grid layout will be stretched to cover the whole grid area it is inside, so if you want elements to have some alignment inside the area you must use wrappers or, if it is just text, align it.

```
.word-bb-1 {
   ...
   text-align: right;
}
```